# Can't login to Virtual OS

Tags: virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a VirtualBox running on RHEL8 and it has RHEL8 installed.

When I tried to login to the OS, after entering the user id and password it goes black for a second and then comes back to ask for login again.

Is there a way to overcome it?

It has some files I'd like to save.

Comment: Just boot into non-graphical mode via the kernel boot line - probably just need `3` at the end of the command line. Or once up and running, get VB to do <CTL>-<ALT>-<F1> and login at the vty prompt. Do you really need to login directly? Can you not just `scp` into it?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching virtual console and see if you can login.
Try changing the kernel commandline before boot to emergency login to access the files this way.
or use another OS, live cd or host to access the virtual os disc image to recover these files.